# Data requests and performance

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax, performance

should i take the new data for my ajax onlinegame worldmap (while dragging/scrolling) from my mysql db or is it better to load the data from a generated (and frequently updated) XML ? (frequently updated -> because of new players joining the game/worldmap)?

in other words:
is mysql capable of dunno a few thousand players scrolling a worldmap (and therefore requesting new data) or should i use a XML sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I hate XML.
For you it might be the right tool for the job, but I'm just going to answer the "is mysql capable of..." part of your question :-)

**Yes**
But it depends on your SQL skills.
How to speed things up?

1. Keep the MySQL server on the same machine as the webserver to avoid network traffic.
2. Use memory tables to avoid disk IO.
3. Know your way around SQL
4. MySQL in de default config is tuned to small tables and small memory sizes, this sounds like it fits your case, but experiment and measure to see which config works best.
5. Fewer selects/inserts/updates with more data per request are faster than more selects/inserts/updates with less data per request.

Also note that if you don't cache the XML file in memory you will hit lock issues on the XML file slowing things down.

Answer (score 0):

A database hit will almost always be more expensive than a file hit (due to crossing a network) - but the quickest option would be to keep an in-memory dataset/cache  (be aware of memory consumption though).

Answer (score 0):

i think mysql fits your need.. you also could cluster your data, when running low on system resources…

also could websockets be intressting for you. maybe you should have look at nodejs, with it you can handle new user joins easily (push the new players to the other players instead of pulling the data out of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Is the Ajax response returned as XML or JSON? If the latter, then why bother messing about with XML?

If it were me, I'd maintain the data in the database with smart serverside caching (where you can invalidate cache items selectively)